# Python class attributes marked read-only when inheriting from dataclass in IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-dataclasses, abc

I have a regular class inheriting from a frozen dataclass.

The attributes in my regular class are marked as 'read-only'. Which I understand due to inheriting the characteristics of the frozen dataclass.

However in IntelliJ these attributes are marked with a red line stating "**Invalid definition and usage of Data Classes options**"

The attributes are still available, and I'm not looking to change them. Is this an IntelliJ thing, throwing up an Inspection which isn't valid? Or am I not understanding inheritance from a dataclass correctly?

Examples:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Page1(ABC):

    something1: thing1
    something2: thing2
```

```
class Page2(Page1):

    def __init__(self, page: BasePage):
        super().__init__(something1=page.thing1,
                         something2=page.thing2)
        self.attr1: str = 'some_string'
        self.attr2 = "Hello"
        self.attr3 = "Goodbye"
```

self.attr1, 2 and 3 look like the following:

[image]

[image]

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would IntelliJ still complain if you move the definitions before you do `super()` to initiate the frozen parent?

Comment: @Torxed Yes still the same when before super()

Comment: If I open the same project in vscode, it doesnt seem to complain, however I have not set up vscode, so not sure if thats a valid test...

Comment: This is in my book valid Python code so it's most likely a IntelliJ incorrectly parsing the frozen scope wider than it actually is *(I'm not a IntelliJ user, just used to Python)*. You should be able to verify this with for instance `mypy --strict <yourfile.py>` which with defaults should tell you right from wrong in most cases.

Comment: What are `thing1`, `thing2` and `BasePage`? Please provide a [mre] which we can just copy into our own IDE to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on the documentation of [@datacalss(frozen=True)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#frozen-instances), doing **any** assignment should raise an error.